# Is it possible for Jenkins to have a quiet time of 0, but restart the build for a limited time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

AFAIK the choices when using Jenkins are to either have a quiet period of 0 in order to start builds immediately upon check-in, or to set a non-zero quiet period in order to catch back-to-back submits.

It seems to me that a better way to do this would be to always start a build immediately, but be willing to abort the build and restart it if there is another submit within a configurable amount of time.

This approach would minimize the cycle time for single submits and allow you to fine tune how you handle busy repositories.

I have searched via Google and stackoverflow and have not been able to find any configuration or plug-in options that would accomplish this.  Does something like this exist or would this be a bad idea for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a "bad idea".

First, you are wasting network bandwidth and CPU cycles doing a partial build that you then abort and chuck out, taking away resources from processes that actually need it.

Second, the principle behind CI is "a build for every commit". If there was a new commit in the middle of the build, you should still have a build for the previous commit and a new build for the new commit, each tested and potentially deployed to DEV/QA.

Developers should be educated to commit their change sets as a single commit, not piecemeal. There is absolutely no valid technical reason that they cannot commit the whole change set at once. The only reasons are laziness to have a proper checkout workspace, and reluctance to change their (flawed and lazy) "I-am-used-to-doing-it-this-way" process.